# HTML5 CSS Centered Image with static footer and left, center and right text

Tags: css, html

I've been trying to get my CSS correct so that I have an image centered vertically and horizontally in the browser no matter what he browser size and screen resolution.

On top of that I'm trying to have a static footer at the bottom of the page that has text left, center and right.  You can see this attempt at http://holiday.lighting

I'm trying to do it all with HTML5 and CSS but it seems I have to give it some weird CSS especially for the footer text to be right aligned otherwise it's off the screen.

Here is my current CSS.

```
html, body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.purple {
    color: #662d91;
}

.green {
    color: #22b24c;
}

.gray {
    color: #b3b2b2;
}

logo {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.logo {
    max-width: 50%;
}

.text {
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #b3b2b2;
    /* 
        Purple: #662d91
        Green: #22b24c
        Gray: #b3b2b2
    */
}

footer {
    background-color: #662d91;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 4px;
    left: 0;
    font-size: x-small;
}

.copyright {
    display: inline;
}

.footerlinks {
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    max-width: 1470px;
}

a {
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
}

a:link {
    color: #ffffff;
}

a:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
}

a:hover {
    color: #b3b2b2;
}

a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Holiday Lighting, LLC</title>
    <link href="styles/holidaylighting.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <logo><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Holiday Lighting Logo" />
        <div class="text">Coming Soon!</div></logo>
    </div>
    <footer><div class="copyright">&copy;2016 Holiday Lighting, LLC</div>
    <div class="footerlinks"><a href="mailto:support@holiday.lighting">Contact Us</a>&bull;<a href="tos.html">Terms of Service</a>&bull;<a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></div></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: I've updated my original question to include the HTML as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, u are just missing some attributes to set the position of fixed elements. For example, in your footer you miss the attribute right: 0, follow your own example:

```css
html, body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.purple {
    color: #662d91;
}

.green {
    color: #22b24c;
}

.gray {
    color: #b3b2b2;
}

logo {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.logo {
    max-width: 50%;
}

.text {
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #b3b2b2;
    /* 
        Purple: #662d91
        Green: #22b24c
        Gray: #b3b2b2
    */
}

footer {
    background-color: #662d91;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 4px;
    left: 0;
    font-size: x-small;
}

.copyright {
    display: inline;
}

.footerlinks {
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    right:0;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    max-width: 1470px;
}

a {
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
}

a:link {
    color: #ffffff;
}

a:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
}

a:hover {
    color: #b3b2b2;
}

a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <logo><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Holiday Lighting Logo" />
        <div class="text">Coming Soon!</div></logo>
    </div>
    <footer><div class="copyright">&copy;2016 Holiday Lighting, LLC</div>
    <div class="footerlinks"><a href="mailto:support@holiday.lighting">Contact Us</a>&bull;<a href="tos.html">Terms of Service</a>&bull;<a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></div></footer>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Seems so obvious I'm not sure how I missed it.